# Find the product of the zeros of g.

Tags: logarithms

Let g(x) = log<sub>5</sub>|2log<sub>3</sub>|. Find the product of the zeros of g.

I did not understand how this function could have zeros as there is no unknown to calculate for. I'm also not sure what the purpose of the absolute value is for.

Comment: $\log_5\lvert2\log_3\rvert$ has no sense since $\log_3$ has no argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In think there is a misprint. The definition should be $g(x)=log_5|2log_3 x|$. This is $0$ iff $2log_3 x=\pm 1$. This means $x=3^{1/2} $ or $x =3^{-1/2}$ and the product of these zeros is $1$.

Comment: Lol a good answer before the very last step... P.S. even without calculation we know that $x$ is a zero iff $x^{-1}$ is a zero, so the product (if makes sense) must be $1$.

Comment: How does dividing 0 by 5 give ±1? (is there any particular rule of logs applied here)

Comment: @V11 $\log_a x=0$ iff $x=1$ for any base $a$. Hence $\log_5|2log_3 x|=0$ iff $|2log_3 x|=1$ which means $2\log_3 x =\pm 1$.

Comment: Ok I get it now, thank you!